# React - How would this look in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started learning react today. How would this simple code look in react? The transition from js rules to react is still kinda hard for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="inp1" /> + <input type="text" id="inp2" />
    <div id="results">=</div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
    <script>
      myFunction = () => {
        const num1 = parseInt(inp1.value);
        const num2 = parseInt(inp2.value);
        const res = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =
          "= The sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + res;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your attemps. Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [num1, setNum1] = useState(null);
  const [num2, setNum2] = useState(null);

  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const myFunction = () => {
    setResult(parseInt(num1, 10) + parseInt(num2, 10));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" onChange={(e) => setNum1(e.target.value)} />
      +
      <input type="number" onChange={(e) => setNum2(e.target.value)} />
      {
        result && <div>The sum of {num1} and {num2} is : {result}</div>
      }
      <button onClick={() => myFunction()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```